# ¿Se puede pasar una variable PHP por POST y a las vez traer datos de vuelta por método GET dentro de una petición Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

por lo de mi pregunta quisiera explicarla para que se entienda.
Me gustaría saber si es posible por medio de una petición **Ajax**(método POST) yo puedo enviar una variable creada en **PHP**  ya la vez traer datos de vuelta de MYSQL por método GET.

Necesito cargar una tabla de MySQL por el Ajax método GET. lo cual logro sin ningún problema. pero me gustaría que a la sentencia MYSQL ponerle un where y asociarle la variable PHP. Pero no logro hacer llegar la variable. quizas ni se pueda hacer eso o tal vez si. esa es mi duda.
ojala alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Hola Alvaro, ¿podrías agregar un ejemplo concreto de lo que necesitas hacer? Sinceramente leyendo tu prengunta no entiendo el problema

Comment: @Marcos mi post de hace unos dias https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332860/como-enviar-una-petición-ajax-con-una-variable
 hay sale lo que busco hacer

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres hacer y creo que se debe a que no entiendes del todo cómo funciona Ajax. Quizá si te olvidas del *cómo*  y nos explicas *el qué*  quieres hacer podamos ayudarte mejor, porque me da que el *cómo*  actual es algo confuso y fuera de todo estándar.

Comment: @A.Cedano tratare de explicarme. y si tienes razón para mi que estoy en aprendiendo. resulta que he utilizado Ajax para poder cargar una tabla proveniente de MYSQL. Soy capaz de cargar la tabla pero no se como pasarle una variable PHP que tengo desde mi pagina principal para poder filtrar por medio de WHERE los datos de mi tabla mira te dejare un link en donde realize la pregunta mas detalla con código y todo : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332860/como-enviar-una-petición-ajax-con-una-variable

Comment: Al parecer lo que quieres es un `select` dependiente o parecido. El tema ha sido tratado varias veces aquí. Es simple: puedes cargar un `select` con los datos de la primera tabla y en el on change de ese select obtienes el `ID` del elemento seleccionado y mandas una petición Ajax con ese `ID` para que te traiga los datos que necesitas en base a ese `ID`, Nada tiene que ver aquí el lío que te haces entre que si GET que si POST y otras historias. Por eso te sugerí que saques en limpio el problema para poder ayudarte mejor...

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129995/29967) se aborda un problema parecido, con explicaciones detalladas. Es **importante** que tengas claro lo que necesitas hacer y cómo funciona Ajax para aplicar un uso correcto en la solución del problema, de lo contrario te encontrarás perdido rápidamente en un laberinto, complicando cosas que son muy sencillas una vez entiendes el funcionamiento.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y consejos. mira implementare como me dices y si me sale algo mal lo comentara para que me ayudes porfavor. muchas gracias